# With git, how to rebase the content of a branch into another while keeping chronological order of commits?

Tags: git

I have three branches:

- dev
- a, created from dev
- b, created from dev

On branch `a`, I have a commit `a1` at 15:33 and another one, `a2`, at 15h35.

On branch `b`, I have a commit `b1` at 15h34.

I want to get these modifications into `dev` and keep the history. I start with branch `a`.

```
git checkout a
git rebase dev
git checkout dev
git merge a
```

This works fine. commits are in the three as I expected them, because the rebase basically had no work to do.

Then I want to obtain the same result with branch `b`.

```
git checkout b
git rebase dev
>fix conflict because there was one that was expected<
git checkout dev
git merge a
```

This creates a situation where the commits are in the following order:

```
b1 15h34
a1 15h33
a2 15h35 >dev<
```

[image]

At this point, if I want to get the history in chronological order, I'll have to `rebase head~4` to reorder the commits. But this will require a force push to the remote, which I want to avoid.

How can I modify my "git flow" or what solution can I use to rebase/merge my feature branches into the dev branch and keep the history clean (chronological order) ?

Comment: Why not cherry pick?

Comment: @matt because I do not know about that and the less command I execute the more the team is happy :D

Comment: @matt What is it with the alteration of my saying ? I said I did not know about that and that if possible I would like to use as few commands as possible. Not that I did not want to use it. Please do not be the type of person that modifies what others are saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two issues here:

First, how do you get the commits in the order you want.  As you noted, you can do once the commits are all in a single branch with `rebase -i`.

The problem you say this has is, you would have to force push.  And if you've already pushed the result of the rebase, then that's true; but the going-forward solution is, do the `rebase -i` before pushing.

Which leads to the second issue:

If you've already pushed the history, how can you fix it without a force push?  To which the answer is: you cannot.

As an aside, I don't recommend doing any of this, at all.  I understand you think it makes sense to want the commits in chronological order.  When you look at how history is actually used, it doesn't; what you're doing is un-grouping related changes by shuffling them together with other groups of changes.

Comment: Thanks, in particular for the side note. It joins with what a collegue told me.